CoreData: Grouped fetch by NSManagedObject
I'm inserting hundreds of thousands of objects using NSBatchInsert, now i want to add relationships between objects (let say A and B, with 1-to-many relationship) as no batch operation supports relationship i will need to use the most efficient and fast way to achieve what I want, the best way I could think of is to use "GroupBy" to fetch object, but this will lead to start a loop to fetch the A entity (as the Key of the Dictionary will be a property not an object).
is there any way to have a Dictionary as fetch result having as Key an NSManagedObject (the A object) and the value an Array of NSManagedObject (B objects) ?
-> let result: [A: [B]]
Thank you

Anything that involves fetching all batch inserted records at once and not even as faults defeats the purpose of using a batch insert. Think about dividing your problem into smaller pieces and fetch a group, establish relationship and continue with the next group.

This is what i did using Swift concurrency using TaskGroup, It was a success (from 1 minute to 35 seconds) but still, it takes too long. What i want is to let CoreData take care of grouping B objects by A objects, so i will not have to fetch Bs when looping into As. And yes, objects are in fault mode (this is the default state when fetching).

How does B know that it belongs to A or vice versa before the relationship is established? You need to provide more information to elaborate the options you might have.

B have the A id it belongs to.

@RedMak what are you going to do with result [A: [B]]? is it for creating relationships?

A dictionary of [A: [B]] efficiently, where A is an NSManagedObject representing the parent entity and [B] is an array of related objects, you’ll need a solution that minimizes looping and fetches while working with Core Data.
Approach 1: Fetch A Entities and Use NSManagedObject Relationships
// Assume we have a managed object context `context`
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<A> = A.fetchRequest()

do {
    let aObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    var result: [A: [B]] = [:]
    
    for a in aObjects {
        if let bObjects = a.bRelation?.allObjects as? [B] {
            result[a] = bObjects
        }
    }
    // Now `result` contains the grouped dictionary
} catch {
    print("Failed to fetch A entities: \(error)")
}

Core Data automatically manages the relationship, so accessing a.bRelation fetches related objects lazily (or eagerly if configured with a Fetch Request for preloading).
Approach 2: Use a Fetch Request with NSDictionaryResultType
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "B")
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

// Assuming "aProperty" is the property that links B to A
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["aProperty"]
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["aProperty"]

do {
    let groupedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    var result: [A: [B]] = [:]

    for group in groupedResults {
        if let aObject = group["aProperty"] as? A {
            let bFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<B> = B.fetchRequest()
            bFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "aProperty == %@", aObject)
            
            let bObjects = try context.fetch(bFetchRequest)
            result[aObject] = bObjects
        }
    }
    // `result` now contains the grouped dictionary
} catch {
    print("Failed to group and fetch: \(error)")
}

NSDictionaryResultType allows you to group objects in the database query itself, reducing the in-memory operation overhead.
Approach 3: Batch Fetch and Process Relationships
let batchSize = 500

// Fetch all B objects in batches
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<B> = B.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = batchSize

do {
    let bObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    var result: [A: [B]] = [:]
    
    for b in bObjects {
        if let a = b.aRelation { // Assuming `aRelation` is the to-one relationship to A
            if result[a] == nil {
                result[a] = []
            }
            result[a]?.append(b)
        }
    }
    // `result` now contains the grouped dictionary
} catch {
    print("Failed to fetch B entities: \(error)")
}

